TypeError: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
I am trying to get data from local storage and display it on the screen using flutter_bloc, but I am getting the error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'". I have checked, but I cannot find a solution.
Someone help me to solve this error...
Below is my code...
And I have added BlockProvider in main.dart file.
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc>(
            create: (context) => ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc()),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: ResumeTempletePreview(isstart: true),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

resume_templete_preview_bloc.dart
class ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc
    extends Bloc<ResumeTemplatePreviewEvent, ResumeTemplatePreviewState> {
  ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc() : super(ResumeTemplatePreviewInitial()) {
    on<LoadResumeData>(_onLoadResumeData);
  }

  void _onLoadResumeData(
      LoadResumeData event, Emitter<ResumeTemplatePreviewState> emit) async {
    emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewLoading());
    try {
      final jsonString = window.localStorage['RESUMEDATA'];
      if (jsonString == null || jsonString.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception('No resume data found in local storage');
      }

      final Map<String, dynamic> resumeData = json.decode(jsonString);
      log("Decoded resume data: $resumeData");

      emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded(resumeData));
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewError(e.toString()));
    }
  }
}

resume_templete_preview_event.dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class ResumeTemplatePreviewEvent extends Equatable {
  const ResumeTemplatePreviewEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadResumeData extends ResumeTemplatePreviewEvent {}

class DownloadResume extends ResumeTemplatePreviewEvent {
  final Uint8List capturedImage;

  const DownloadResume(this.capturedImage);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [capturedImage];
}

resume_templete_preview_state.dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class ResumeTemplatePreviewState extends Equatable {
  const ResumeTemplatePreviewState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ResumeTemplatePreviewInitial extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {}

class ResumeTemplatePreviewLoading extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {}

class ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {
  final Map<String, dynamic> resumeData;

  const ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded(this.resumeData);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [resumeData];
}

class ResumeTemplatePreviewError extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {
  final String message;

  const ResumeTemplatePreviewError(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

class ResumeDownloading extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {}

class ResumeDownloaded extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {}

class ResumeDownloadError extends ResumeTemplatePreviewState {
  final String message;

  const ResumeDownloadError(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

resume_templete_preview.dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/core/colors/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/core/constants/dimens.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/models/education.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/models/employment.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/models/personal_skill.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/models/professional_skill.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/models/skill.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/screens/resume_template/resume_template1.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/screens/resume_template/resume_template2.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/screens/resume_templete_preview/resume_templete_preview_bloc/resume_templete_preview_bloc.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/screens/resume_templete_preview/resume_templete_preview_bloc/resume_templete_preview_event.dart';
import 'package:quick_resume_creator/screens/resume_templete_preview/resume_templete_preview_bloc/resume_templete_preview_state.dart';

class ResumeTempletePreview extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic extra;
  final bool isstart;
  const ResumeTempletePreview({super.key, this.extra, required this.isstart});

  @override
  State<ResumeTempletePreview> createState() => _ResumeTempletePreviewState();
}

class _ResumeTempletePreviewState extends State<ResumeTempletePreview> {
  String resumeIndex = "";

  late ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (_scrollController.offset >= 300) {
          showBackToTopButton = true;
        } else {
          showBackToTopButton = false;
        }
      });
    });

    super.initState();

    context.read<ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc>().add(LoadResumeData());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.authBgcolor,
        appBar: _buildappbar(),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Divider(color: AppColors.dividercolor, height: 1),
            buildSizedBoxH(50),
            BlocBuilder<ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc, ResumeTemplatePreviewState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is ResumeTemplatePreviewLoading) {
                  log("state is ResumeTemplatePreviewLoading");
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (state is ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded) {
                  log("state is ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded");
                  resumeIndex = state.resumeData['id'] != null &&
                          state.resumeData['id'] != ""
                      ? state.resumeData['id'].toString()
                      : "1";
                } else if (state is ResumeTemplatePreviewError) {
                  log("state is ResumeTemplatePreviewError");
                  return Center(child: Text(state.message));
                }
                return getResumeTemplate(resumeIndex);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget getResumeTemplate(String status) {
    switch (status) {
      case '1':
        return ResumeTemplate1(
          customerFirstNametext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME'].toString(),
          customerLastNametext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERLASTNAME'].toString(),
          customerProfileImageURL:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFILEIMAGE'].toString(),
          customerProfessiontext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSION'].toString(),
          customerLocationtext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERLOCATION'].toString(),
          customerWebsitetext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERWEBSITE'].toString(),
          customerPhoneNotext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPHONENO'].toString(),
          customerEmailIDtext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREMAILID'].toString(),
          customerProfessionalSummarytext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSIONALSUMMARY'].toString(),
          customerEducationList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREDUCATIONLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Education>((item) => Education.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerEmploymentList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREMPLOYMENTLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Employment>((item) => Employment.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerProfessionalSkillList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSIONALSKILLLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<ProfessionalSkill>(
                      (item) => ProfessionalSkill.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerPersonalSkillList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPERSONALSKILLLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<PersonalSkill>((item) => PersonalSkill.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
        );
      case '2':
        return ResumeTemplate2(
          customerFirstNametext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME'].toString(),
          customerLastNametext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERLASTNAME'].toString(),
          customerProfileImageURL:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFILEIMAGE'].toString(),
          customerProfessiontext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSION'].toString(),
          customerLocationtext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERLOCATION'].toString(),
          customerWebsitetext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERWEBSITE'].toString(),
          customerPhoneNotext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPHONENO'].toString(),
          customerEmailIDtext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREMAILID'].toString(),
          customerProfessionalSummarytext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSIONALSUMMARY'].toString(),
          customerEducationList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREDUCATIONLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Education>((item) => Education.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerEmploymentList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREMPLOYMENTLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Employment>((item) => Employment.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerSkillList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMERSKILLLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Skill>((item) => Skill.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
        );
      default:
        return ResumeTemplate1(
          customerFirstNametext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME'].toString(),
          customerLastNametext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERLASTNAME'].toString(),
          customerProfileImageURL:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFILEIMAGE'].toString(),
          customerProfessiontext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSION'].toString(),
          customerLocationtext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERLOCATION'].toString(),
          customerWebsitetext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERWEBSITE'].toString(),
          customerPhoneNotext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPHONENO'].toString(),
          customerEmailIDtext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREMAILID'].toString(),
          customerProfessionalSummarytext:
              window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSIONALSUMMARY'].toString(),
          customerEducationList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREDUCATIONLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Education>((item) => Education.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerEmploymentList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMEREMPLOYMENTLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<Employment>((item) => Employment.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerProfessionalSkillList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPROFESSIONALSKILLLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<ProfessionalSkill>(
                      (item) => ProfessionalSkill.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
          customerPersonalSkillList:
              (jsonDecode(window.localStorage['CUSTOMERPERSONALSKILLLIST']!)
                      as List<dynamic>)
                  .map<PersonalSkill>((item) => PersonalSkill.fromJson(item))
                  .toList(),
        );
    }
  }
}

This is my Debug Console...
Restarted application in 244ms.
[log] TypeError: "{\"uid\":\"ryln8SHS9fg7cTE7sTdwS4dzmeH2\",\"id\":\"6\",\"resumeid\":\"fXFhqH02zX8iv8THRVB1\",\"customerFirstNametext\":\"Testing\",\"customerLastNametext\":\"Testing\",\"customerProfileImage\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/quick-resume-creator.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fryln8SHS9fg7cTE7sTdwS4dzmeH2%2FfXFhqH02zX8iv8THRVB1%2F1720696073185.jpg?alt=media&token=8c803ce4-4a98-43f2-b630-ccec214a317f\",\"customerProfessiontext\":\"Testing\",\"customerLocationtext\":\"Testing\",\"customerWebsitetext\":\"www.testing.com\",\"customerPhoneNotext\":\"7894561230\",\"customerEmailIDtext\":\"testing@gmail.com\",\"customerProfessionalSummarytext\":\"TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting.\",\"customerEducationList\":[{\"university\":\"Testing\",\"degree\":\"Testing\",\"startDate\":\"Jul 2023\",\"endDate\":\"Jul 2033\"}],\"customerEmploymentList\":[{\"jobTitle\":\"Testing\",\"companyName\":\"Testing\",\"startDate\":\"Jul 2023\",\"endDate\":\"Jul 2025\",\"address\":\"Testing\"}],\"customerProfessionalSkillList\":[],\"customerPersonalSkillList\":[],\"customerSkillList\":[{\"skill\":\"Testing\",\"level\":60},{\"skill\":\"Testing\",\"level\":40},{\"skill\":\"Testing\",\"level\":40}],\"customerSkillLavel\":0}": type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
[log] state is ResumeTemplatePreviewError

Please help me to solve this error...

your jsonString starts (and ends) with " so it is decoded as String and not a Map

Can you print jsonString before invoking json.decode(jsonString) to see the actual data

@AlexSunderSingh it is printed in the logs

[log] QuickResumeData(uid: ryln8SHS9fg7cTE7sTdwS4dzmeH2, id: 6, resumeid: fXFhqH02zX8iv8THRVB1, customerFirstNametext: Testing, customerLastNametext: Testing,.....)
this is log before invoking 'json.decode(jsonString)' @AlexSunderSingh

As @pskink said, your jsonString has " at start and end, we may need to trim it from the string

your jsonString starts with " - it is decoded as String not Map - you can see how it works by running: `import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
final d0 = jsonDecode('""');
final d1 = jsonDecode('{}');
final d2 = jsonDecode('"{}"');
print('d0 is String: ${d0 is String}');
print('d1 is Map: ${d1 is Map}');
print('d2 is Map: ${d2 is Map}');
print('d2 is String: ${d2 is String}');
}` in the https://dartpad.dev

and of course you should not fix it by removing starting and ending " (because you would also need to replace every \" with ") but instead  trying to figure out why window.localStorage['RESUMEDATA'] contains that buggy data - this is your real root problem

It's done, I removed the slashes and quotes and passed their values. Started working properly. Thanks for giving me suggestions AlexSunderSingh and pskink
image of code

no., this is not how you should do that, instead you have to make sure that your stored data is a Valid json string - i mean window.localStorage['RESUMEDATA'] has to contain a valid json string

You mean, check where slashes and quotes come from in the json string? @pskink

yes, exactly: you should fix the problem as soon as possible, not when parsing your data, what if you need to do that in other place - would you repeat your code with replaceAll again and again?

Your jsonString contains " at the start and end, so if you are sure that the string starts and ends with " you need to trim it manually.
try {
  String? jsonString = window.localStorage['RESUMEDATA'];
  if (jsonString == null || jsonString.isEmpty) {
    throw Exception('No resume data found in local storage');
  }
  if (jsonString.startsWith('"')){
     jsonString = jsonString.substring(1);
  }
  if (jsonString.endsWith('"')){
     jsonString = jsonString.substring(0, jsonString.length - 1);
  }
  jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(r'\"', '"');

  final Map<String, dynamic> resumeData = json.decode(jsonString);
  log("Decoded resume data: $resumeData");

  emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded(resumeData));
} catch (e) {
  log(e.toString());
  emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewError(e.toString()));
}

Try with this snippet in your class ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc

you're trying to decode a string into a Map<String, dynamic>, but it's failing because the string might not be valid JSON or is not being decoded correctly
try this error-handling.
    _onLoadResumeData(LoadResumeData event, Emitter<ResumeTemplatePreviewState> emit) async {emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewLoading());
  try {
    final jsonString = window.localStorage['RESUMEDATA'];
    if (jsonString == null || jsonString.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception('No resume data found in local storage');
    }
    // Log the jsonString for debugging
    print("Retrieved resume data JSON: $jsonString");
    // Decode jsonString into Map<String, dynamic>
    final Map<String, dynamic> resumeData = json.decode(jsonString);
    // Log decoded resume data for debugging
    print("Decoded resume data: $resumeData");
    emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewLoaded(resumeData));
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error loading resume data: $e");
    emit(ResumeTemplatePreviewError(e.toString()));
  }
}


BlocBuilder Error:
Error: Unexpected null value in BlocBuilder<ResumeTemplatePreviewBloc, ResumeTemplatePreviewState>.
Cause: The bloc value is null.
||
JSON Parsing Error:
Error: TypeError stating a String is not a subtype of Map<String, dynamic>.
Cause: The retrieved JSON data is being interpreted incorrectly, possibly due to malformed JSON or incorrect parsing logic.
